# Opening a new window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

When i click a particular video in grid view that video should be played in a new window.

When i click a video in grid view i will check certain conditions in server side page. Only if that condition is true i want to play that video in new window (or) tab.

If that condition is false then i want to play the selected video in the same page itself.

**This is my code:**

```
if(videoCategoryName.CategoryName=="Syndicated Videos")
{ 
  string url = www.planetwrox.com + "/" +  "default.aspx?q=videoid
  string fullURL = "window.open('www.google.com', '_blank', 'height=500,width=800');";
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", fullURL, true);
}
```

But new is not opened. instead the video plays in the same window.

Can any one provide some ideas or code to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it using jQuery:

```
ClientScriptManager clientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript;
string scriptText = "$(document).ready(function() { window.open('http://www.google.com'); });";
clientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", scriptText, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

i can see one extra single quote before height=500, which is not closed. Is that the reason!

Comment: I even added, the closing quotes even then its not opening in a new window.....Is there any other way to implement this task...

Ur thoughts

Comment: you can place your video control into anchor tags
<a href=..."> video control </a>
attach href source to these anchor tag at run time to open corresponding videos...

else you can may be find your answer here
http://forums.asp.net/t/1517167.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try `var win = window.open()` instead of just `window.open()`